# Grails: how to save value to transient field while unit test with spock?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, transactions, spock

In order to test a domain class, which has a transient field, I tried to put a value for that field by the two following ways:

```
Requirement requirement = new Requirement(linearProduct: linearProduct, periodIndexes: [1,2,3])
requirement.periodIndexes = [1,2,3]
```

Both of them made the field appear as null object when getting into the tested function.

My question is how to make the values pass although it transient field?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to be sure what is going on.  The subject begins with "how to save".  I am not sure if you are talking about persisting to the database or not.  See my answer below.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

The solution was to have a mocked get function to the field in it's domain class:

```
        Requirement.metaClass.'static'.getPeriodIndexes = {[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Making that method `static` (as in `Requirement.metaClass.'static'.getPeriodIndexes = {[1,2,3]}`) is also a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

Transient properties are `bindable:false` by default.  If you want the periodIndexes field to be bindable with named arguments you have to be explicit about that:

```
class Requirement {
    transient List periodIndexes

    static constraints = {
        periodIndexes bindable: true
    }
}
```

It isn't clear why your `requirement.periodIndexes = [1,2,3]` results in null.  It shouldn't.  If you can show a more complete test I can help you with that.

**EDIT:**

As an example...

A domain class:

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Widget.groovy
package demo

class Widget {
    String name
    transient List firstTransientList
    transient List secondTransientList

    static constraints = {
        secondTransientList bindable: true
    }
}
```

This test will pass:

```
// test/unit/demo/WidgetSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(Widget)
class WidgetSpec extends Specification {

    void "test binding to transient fields"() {
        when: 'binding to transient properties using named arguments'
        def widget = new Widget(firstTransientList: [1, 2, 3], 
                                secondTransientList: [4, 5, 6])

        then: 'by default transient fields are not bindable'
        widget.firstTransientList == null

        and: 'transient fields configured with bindable:true are bindable'
        widget.secondTransientList == [4, 5, 6]

        when: 'a value is assigned directly to a transient property'
        widget.firstTransientList = [7, 8, 9]

        then: 'the assignment succeeds'
        widget.firstTransientList == [7, 8, 9]
    }
}
```

You haven't said which version of Grails you are using.  Some of this behavior changed in the 2.3.x line.  The test above should pass with recent versions of Grails.

**ANOTHER EDIT (to answer a question in a comment below):**

The transient properties may be defined without the `transient` keyword but instead using the `transients` property, as shown below:

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Widget.groovy
package demo

class Widget {
    String name
    List firstTransientList
    List secondTransientList

    static transients = ['firstTransientList', 'secondTransientList']

    static constraints = {
        secondTransientList bindable: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this issue by still using "static transients = ['periodIndexes']"  ?

Comment: Yes.  That works exactly the same way.  Remove the `transient` keyword from the `periodIndexes` definition and instead use `static transients = ['periodIndexes']`.

Comment: I don't want that this field will be saved in DB, i'ts only used for tests

Comment: If it is transient it will not be saved to the database. However, if you have properties in your domain class that are only there to support tests then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Ok, what is the best practice in this case?

Comment: If you are asking about using the transient keyword vs. the transients property, call it personal preference.  For most cases it won't matter.

Comment: Actually i'm asking what should I do in order to use this field defined as 'transient' in production while it can be also used in tests. 
Currently it's working fine at development, but when it comes to testing, the field becomes null

Comment: I don't know what "it's working fine at development, but when it comes to testing, the field becomes null" might mean.  I am sorry that I haven't been able to help you.  Best of luck.

Comment: I just need to know how to fix this issue when testing using spock, the current optional solution is above, but is there any other one?